# Site-to-site VPN - Group Policy failing as UNC path is inaccessible

Tags: vpn, windows-sbs-2008

We have a site-to-site VPN configured using a DrayTek router with the domain controller at the main office.

I can access '\\server\sysvol' via the VPN tunnel at the satellite office, however the '\\domain.local\sysvol\' path is inaccessible.

This causes group policy processing upon logon to fail, and also causes slow logon times as Windows looks for the policy using the domain at the root of the UNC rather than the server's hostname.

Is there any way around this, by either changing the path that group policy uses, or somehow getting resolution to '\\domain.local\sysvol\' working?

There is only one domain controller. We are using Windows SBS 2008.

Comment: What's your dns setup on the DrayTek router?
Is your SBS the first DNS server forwarded??

Comment: Hi, I've just changed the DNS servers on the router, primary to point to the server, and secondary to Google Public DNS, so we shall see what happens. I'll let you know if it makes a difference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would comment on your original post, but don't have enough reputation points.

This may be helpful: https://serverfault.com/a/1151127/366936

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/572517)